# Variable character inside a constant

Tags: c, character, constants

Having defined this:

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
int var3 = 3;
```

I want to make this:

```
int result = varc * 70; // Where c is a previously defined int that can take 1,2 or 3 value.
```

Solutions? Thank you.

Comment: **_previously defined_** : what does it means? A variable that can change runtime, or defined at compile time?

Comment: A variable that can change runtime.

Comment: Well, so @Bathsheba 's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C you're out of luck on this since it's not a *reflective* language. That is you can't get the value of a variable by somehow "stringifying" the name you gave it in the source code.

But what you could do is use an *array*:

```
int vars[] = {1, 2, 3};

int result = vars[i] * 70;
```

where `i` is 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: Taking the value `vars[i]` seems run-time where initialization is compile-time. Any explanation why this is valid?

Comment: The note to make is that `int result = vars[i] * 70;` can only be in a function (i.e., `result` is an automatic variable) because the calculation of the initializer is run-time and not compile-time (not a constant expression). I feel Bathsheba's solution is confusing without this remark.

Answer (score 2):

you write:

```
int result = varc * 70;
```

This is what you want to make is not possible in language c.

Note:  *varc* is an identifier

Remember **IDENTIFIER in C :**
                      Identifiers are names for entities in a C program, such as variables, arrays, functions, structures, unions.

It must be unique for all entities and also **an identifier is a string of alphanumeric characters**

Ok, you remembered.   **:)**

So, you never used "c" present in "varc" to treat(refer) to other variables/identifies/entities.

I hope I might be solve your doubt in easiest way .Thank you! :)